# ubuntu trusty: files lost in encypted home dir

Tags: home-directory, ecryptfs

help. i'm missing files in my ecryptfs home directory and wondering if there is a way to recover.  i had a number of files open in vim inside a tmux session and i suspect that my home directory was remounted at some point. any files i had saved in vim after this point seem to have gone to a black hole.

i've been able to reproduce what i think has happened by logging out, logging back in and then rejoining my tmux session:

pwd shows my current path as unreachable:

```
➜ ~>pwd

(unreachable)/
```

if i edit a file in my home dir without noticing this had happened:

```
➜ ~>echo test > test

➜ ~>cat test

test
```

and then `cd` to my home directory (the same place i thought i was), the file is gone:

```
➜ ~>cd

➜ ~>cat test 

cat: test: No such file or directory

➜ ~>ls -l test 

ls: cannot access test: No such file or directory

➜ ~>ls
ls: cannot access test: No such file or directory
Downloads/             Music/              RestConf.json               vcs-vlan.retry
Dropbox/               my_playbook2.retry  settings/
...
```

is there anywhere this file may have been saved?  i've checked the mount path with the ecryptfs filesystem unmounted, but no luck.  any ideas?